# Django - Different URLs for Production and Development?

Tags: django, url

Is it possible to have two different urls.py files for one project, using one of them all the time, but then invoking the second for development purposes?

What I want is this:

For production (and is live 24/7) I want the following links:

```
www.mydomain.com
www.mydomain.com/about/
www.mydomain.com/contact/
```

But for development (which I use the `runserver` now and then as I test) I want all the base links, plus a few more:

```
www.mydomain.com
www.mydomain.com/about/
www.mydomain.com/contact/
www.mydomain.com/secret/sauce/
www.mydomain.com/punchanella/in/the/zoo/
www.mydomain.com/me/too/
```

So effectively the outside world does not even know that my extra links exist since they don't have any access to them.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it like this

In your settings.py set the following

```
LOCAL_DEV = True
```

then in your urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings
if settings.LOCAL_DEV:
  urlpatterns = patterns('',
   #
   # all your other urls here for dev
   #
)
```

Comment: Branching for different envs in your code is not what I would consider a best practice, yet it does seem to be the overwhelmingly most popular option for this particular use case, which is disappointing.

Answer (score 1):

Django defines the [`ROOT_URLCONF`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#root-urlconf) parameter for this use case. Example for different URL sets for development and production environment: create two different `urls` modules, for example `urls_dev` and `urls_prod` with different `urlpatterns`. Project structure:

```
myproj
├── models.py
├── views.py
├── ...
├── urls_dev.py
└── urls_prod.py
```

In your settings, redefine `ROOT_URLCONF` depending on what environment you are currently in:

```
# settings.py

if os.environ.get('DEVELOPMENT', None):
    ROOT_URLCONF = 'myproj.urls_dev'
else:
    ROOT_URLCONF = 'myproj.urls_prod'
```

or even split the single settings into two different modules, `settings_dev` and `settings_prod`, each defining its own `ROOT_URLCONF`. Then start the server with the selected settings:

```
$ django-admin runserver --settings=myproj.settings_dev
```

Comment: I like this answer.  Instead of branching in your code, use an env var or CLI option to set the correct settings file which drives the rest of the changes.